# Nintex workflow action - "Create item in another site" adds html tags automatically

Tags: workflow, nintex

I have created a Nintex workflow (SharePoint 2013) which is triggered when an item is created or modified in a list. The workflow only creates/updates this item in another list (target list).

The problem I have is pretty strange - One of the populated fields ("Ongoing studies & due date" field) in the target list is populated with HTML tags as you can see below here:

[image]

The "Ongoing studies & due date" field should consists of text only, these HTML tags were added automatically.

I'm going out of my head to solve this problem so any help is welcome!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the type of this column Ongoing studies and due date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this have a look at the type of the column **Ongoing studies and due date** , if it is Multiple lines of text and if you don't want any rich text then select the option **Plain text** under specify the type of the text to allow from column settings .

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This issue occurs because of the source field is a `multi-text rich text` and the destination is a `multi-text with plain`

So make sure that the `type of text` in column setting is the same in source and destination list

[image]

Comment: Should you set it as answer if it solved your issue :) , you do it and rollback again :) No Problem :) you are welcome :)